# How can I load data from mongo before the page load with KeystoneJS?

Tags: mongodb, express, handlebars.js, middleware, keystonejs

I'm using KeystoneJS with Handlebars for the views. I've been trying to get a list of companies from MongoDB to load in the navigation bar, without success. I know where to go to update the navLinks and I can load the companies from mongodb on a single page. I want to load the list of companies on all the pages in the navigation and the list of compangies is not static. Where would I put my code to load the data before the navigation renders?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own local variables in the 'initLocals' middleware in routes/middleware.js, which will run before route controllers are executed:

*routes/middleware.js*

```
exports.initLocals = function(req, res, next) {

    var locals = res.locals;

    locals.user = req.user;

    // Add your own local variables here

    next();

};
```

Checkout the **Common Route Middleware** section in the Keystone.js docs:
http://keystonejs.com/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work

```
exports.initLocals = function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals.navLinks = [
            { label: 'Accueil',         key: 'home',        href: '/' },
            { label: 'Projets',         key: 'projects',    href: '/projects' },
            { label: 'Contacts',        key: 'users',       href: '/contacts' },
            { label: 'Livrables',       key: 'deliverables',href: '/deliverables' },
            { label: 'Fichier sources', key: 'sources',     href: '/sources' }
        ];

        //Get available companies for the user
        var view = new keystone.View(req,res);
        view.query('companies', keystone.list('Company').model.find().populate('project').sort('title')).then(function (err, results, next) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            next();
        });
        view.render(function(){
            next();
        });
    };
```